# fast looping for user written functions

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have written two functions
a) the first create simulated data and estimates a model
b) the second iterates this process a number of times, and average statistics from multiple simulations.

The third step I would like to do is to iterate this process across different sample sizes. I know how to do this with a for loop but it takesvery long. Does anyone has suggestions on how to improve looping speed?

In particular, I would be interested in using parallel processing or evaluating alternative looping packages like `purrr`.

Here is an example:

```
# create a the first function simulates data and estimates the model
genmodel <- function (n,meanx,meany){
  df <- as.data.frame(list(mean_x=rnorm(n=n, mean=meanx, sd=1)))
  df <- df %>%   mutate(mean_y=rnorm(n=n, mean=meany, sd=1))
  model<- lm_robust(mean_y ~ mean_x, data=df,
                    se_type = "stata")
  pval<- as.data.frame(list(p=summary(model)$coefficients)) %>% t() 
  pval <- as.data.frame(pval) %>% rownames_to_column() 
return(pval)
}
# example
> genmodel(n=100,meanx=2,meany=1)
       rowname  (Intercept)      mean_x
1   p.Estimate 9.984653e-01 -0.05115484
2 p.Std..Error 2.027905e-01  0.10273142
3    p.t.value 4.923630e+00 -0.49794738
4   p.Pr...t.. 3.441203e-06  0.61963671
5   p.CI.Lower 5.960341e-01 -0.25502201
6   p.CI.Upper 1.400896e+00  0.15271232
7         p.DF 9.800000e+01 98.00000000
```

Generate the second function that that iterate the first function a number of times and averages estimated statistics

```
average_model <- function(nrep=100, # number of simulations
                      n,
                      mean_x,
                      mean_y
){
tmpres<- lapply(1:nrep, function(x) genmodel(n=n,meanx=mean_x,meany=mean_y))
tmpres <- do.call(rbind, tmpres)
vec<- names(tmpres[2:ncol(tmpres)])
tmpres <- unique(setDT(tmpres)[,paste("avg",(vec),sep = "_"):=map(.SD,~ mean(.x)),by=rowname,.SDcols=(vec)
][,nobs:=n] %>% select(rowname,`avg_(Intercept)`,avg_mean_x,nobs))
}


# example
tst<-average_model(nrep=50,n=100,mean_x=2,mean_y=1)
        rowname avg_(Intercept)  avg_mean_x nobs
1:   p.Estimate      1.06002378 -0.03100749  100
2: p.Std..Error      0.22368299  0.09921118  100
3:    p.t.value      4.83878275 -0.31190506  100
4:   p.Pr...t..      0.00206157  0.45198433  100
5:   p.CI.Lower      0.61613217 -0.22788884  100
6:   p.CI.Upper      1.50391540  0.16587386  100
7:         p.DF     98.00000000 98.00000000  100
```

Now my objective is to iterate this `average_model` function over different sample sizes and to create a unique data frame with all of the information. This can be easily done using a `for` loop

```
for (i in seq(from=100,to=500,by=30)){ 
  tmpres <- average_model(nrep=50,n=i,mean_x=2,mean_y=1)
  results <- rbind(results, tmpres) # sequentially paste results
head(results)
        rowname avg_(Intercept)   avg_mean_x nobs
1:   p.Estimate     1.001296821  0.000989775  100
2: p.Std..Error     0.224800002  0.099078646  100
3:    p.t.value     4.530076894  0.027428073  100
4:   p.Pr...t..     0.001934362  0.504152193  100
5:   p.CI.Lower     0.555188534 -0.195628574  100
6:   p.CI.Upper     1.447405108  0.197608124  100

# it can also be done using `apply`, but both approach are quite slow


tmpres<- lapply(seq(from=100,to=500,by=30), function(x) average_model(nrep=50,n=x,mean_x=2,mean_y=1)
tmpres <- do.call(rbind, tmpres)
```

The problem with this for loop is that it is extremely slow.

Is there a way I could do this using parallel processing? Other suggestions for reducing running time?

Comment: The `foreach` package is usually an easy way to use parallel processing. Using `rbind` in a loop is a classic performance killer - better to create a list of results and `rbind` them all at the end. See [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for a full treatment of that.

Comment: Specifically chapter 2: Growing Objects.

Comment: There are other steps in your code here that seem unnecessarily complicated: `as.data.frame(list(...))` --> `data.frame(...)` (in multiple places); also replace the two `df` lines with `df <- data.frame(mean_x=rnorm(..), mean_y=rnorm(..))` and do it in one step. And stop calling `as.data.frame(.)` on objects are you previously converted to a frame; it's usually close to a no-op, but it does add unnecessary layers to your code. Don't explicitly use `return(pval)`, just use `pval`; again, minor, but microseconds ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "all `data.table`" approach is about twice as fast, but still disappointing.

The basic idea is to assemble all the datasets into one large `data.table` and then cycle through the models using `data.table` group by.

```
library(data.table)
library(estimatr)
library(tictoc)
##
tic()
mf     <- data.table(nrep=1:50, meanx=2, meany=1)
mf     <- mf[, .(n=seq(100, 500, 30)), by=.(nrep, meanx, meany)]
data   <- mf[, .(mean_x=rnorm(n, meanx), mean_y=rnorm(n, meany)), by=.(n, nrep, meanx, meany)]
result <- data[, as.data.table(t(summary(lm(mean_y~mean_x, .SD, se_type = 'stata'))$coefficients), keep.rownames = TRUE)
               , by=.(n, nrep, meanx, meany)][, nrep:=NULL]
result <- result[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=.(n, meanx, meany, rn)]
toc()
## 2.58 sec elapsed
```

So this takes between 2.3 - 2.6 sec on my machine, wheres your code runs in about 4.0 - 4.1 sec. About 80% of the time is spent running `lm_robust(...)`. If I swap that out for `lm(...)` in base R it runs in about 1 sec.

Comment: Thanks this is for sure an improvement, do you know if I cold speed this up further with parallel processing?

Comment: You cannot parallelize `data.table` group by. This is by design. You might be able to speed up the loop-based approach with parallel processing but generally you need many more than n processors to get an n-fold improvement.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done more straight forward:

```r
expand_grid(
  nreps = 50,
  n = seq.default(100, 500, by = 30),
  mean_x = 2, mean_y = 1
) %>% 
  rowid_to_column("n_idx") %>% 
  uncount(nreps, .remove = FALSE) %>% 
  rowid_to_column("nreps_idx") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    lm_robust = 
      estimatr::lm_robust(
        y ~ X,
        data = 
          tibble(y = rnorm(n, mean = mean_y, sd = 1),
                 X = rnorm(n, mean = mean_x, sd = 1)),
        se_type = "stata"
      ) %>% 
      coefficients() %>% 
      set_names(str_c("coef_", names(.))) %>% 
      list()
  ) %>% 
  unnest_wider(lm_robust) %>% 
  group_by(nreps_idx) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = unique(n),
    across(starts_with("coef"), mean),
  )
```

Which result in

```r
# A tibble: 700 × 4
   nreps_idx     n `coef_(Intercept)`  coef_X
       <int> <dbl>              <dbl>   <dbl>
 1         1   100              1.34  -0.183 
 2         2   100              0.845  0.0188
 3         3   100              0.949  0.0341
 4         4   100              1.20  -0.0705
 5         5   100              0.731  0.0419
 6         6   100              0.809  0.0564
 7         7   100              0.920  0.0558
 8         8   100              1.22  -0.0673
 9         9   100              1.22  -0.171 
10        10   100              1.26  -0.127 
# … with 690 more rows
```

Which is computed fairly quickly.

Now, I've not included all the parameters in your code, because honestly it doesn't make sense to take the mean of them, but if you want them as well then...

```r
expand_grid(
  nreps = 50,
  n = seq.default(100, 500, by = 30),
  mean_x = 2, mean_y = 1
) %>% 
  rowid_to_column("n_idx") %>% 
  uncount(nreps, .remove = FALSE) %>% 
  rowid_to_column("nreps_idx") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    lm_robust = 
      estimatr::lm_robust(
        y ~ X,
        data = 
          tibble(y = rnorm(n, mean = mean_y, sd = 1),
                 X = rnorm(n, mean = mean_x, sd = 1)),
        se_type = "stata"
      ) %>% 
      # SECOND APPROACH
      summary() %>% 
      `[[`("coefficients") %>%
      as_tibble(rownames = "rowname") %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = "rowname", 
                  values_from = everything()) %>% 
      # FIRST APPROACH
      # coefficients() %>% 
      # set_names(str_c("coef_", names(.))) %>% 
      list()
  ) %>% 
  unnest_wider(lm_robust) %>% 
  print() %>% 
  group_by(nreps_idx) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = unique(n),
    across(starts_with("Estimate"), mean),
    # insert statements here to summarise the other gathered stuff
  )
```

But this makes things unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, the approach you suggest works, but it is hardly generalisable to more complex functions. I was looking for a more general way of speeding this up either using a more efficient package or by  using parallel processing! any idea?